# Array loop not working

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I've tried this:

```
if (argc > 2) {
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    if(i != 0) {
      rename_file(argv[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

if I pass in two file names only the first is renamed, whats wrong with this loop?

**EDIT**: Heres the rename_file function (it should work I think)

```
void rename_file(char const *filename) {
  struct tm *clock;
  struct stat attrib;
  const char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
  const char *ext = NULL;
  if (dot && *dot) {
      ext = dot + 1;
  }

  stat(filename, &attrib);

  clock = gmtime(&(attrib.st_mtime));

  char newname[250];
  if (!ext) {
    printf("ERROR: No File Extenstion");
  } else {
    sprintf(newname, "%02d_%02d_%02d.%s", clock->tm_mday, clock->tm_mon, clock->tm_year + 1900, ext);
  }

  rename(filename, newname);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Are you sure `rename_file` works correctly? Btw. you can omit the `if` statement and initialize `i` with `1`.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the loop?

Comment: That depends on what rename_file does/is intended to do

Comment: It would be simpler if you initialised i to 1 and removed the `if(i != 0)` check.

Comment: To help diagnose what's going on, before the `rename_file` call add a line saying something like `fprintf(stderr, "renaming: %s\n", argv[i]);` and see whether you're getting a message for both the files you passed in. (Or, e.g., a single message that for some reason contains both filenames, or whatever.) I agree that the loop itself doesn't seem to have a bug that would cause the problem you describe. [EDITED to remove something redundant with an earlier comment added while I was writing that.]

Comment: not relevant to whatever your bug is, but please considering naming your files 'yyyy_mm_dd.ext' instead - that way they'll sort into the correct date order automatically.

Comment: Your `rename_file` function will leave a file un-renamed if (1) the file already has the same name as you're trying to give it, or (2) for some reason the `rename` call fails. You should, at the very least, check the return value from `rename` and do something appropriate if it didn't work. What happens if you pass the same two filenames in the opposite order? Does the second one then work and the first fail, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (argc > 2) {
  for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      rename_file(argv[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This should not make a difference.

Comment: that's certainly a bug, but it doesn't explain what he's seeing.

Comment: I agree that *errorhandler* should be checking for `argc >= 2` rather than `argc > 2`, but the problem s/he describes occurs in a situation where `argc > 2` is actually true, so your proposal can't solve that problem.

Comment: @muntoo: That depends on what the application is supposed to do. Now you changed your answer (*before that, the only change was `argc >= 2` instead of `argc > 2`, and this is what my comment referred to*). Maybe it requires two arguments? You don't know!

Comment: @errorhandler: This does exactly the same as your original code. If this works it just means your problem isn't happening all the time.

Comment: @Erik no it never worked for the second file until I changed that code.

Comment: @Erik Perhaps his code contains some undefined behaviour? (Unallocated pointers/etc)

Comment: @errorhandler Perhaps you passed the files wrong? The code is really equivalent. And I doubt it's a GCC bug.

Comment: @muntoo nope I run `./renamer *.tiff` and press tab then `./renamer asdf.tiff test.tiff`

Answer (score 0):

If your command line looks like this:

```
./renamestuff stuff.txt stuff.php
```

Then you probably want this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    rename_file(argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the `if (argc > 1)` test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a bug as such, but I do see a lot of redundancy in the code. You could just do this:

```
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    rename_file(argv[i]);
}
```

If you don't have a debugger then you could add some debug `printf`s temporarily:

```
printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    printf("i = %d, argv[i] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    rename_file(argv[i]);
}
```

This will let you see what's going on in the loop prior to each call to `rename_file`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the return value of `rename`. If you pass the name of two files created on the same date (and with same extension), the second will likely fail (this is depending on your c lib though). And, fix your loop as everyone else pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

The first element `argv[0]` contains the name of the executable itself. Therefore your loop should start with the first element.

Comment: that's what he does (testing against i == 0). Can be reworked of course but this answer does not address the question.

Comment: perhaps because it's irrelevant and already accounted for (albeit poorly) in the OP's code?

Comment: @BlackBear: This does not seem to be a solution to the problem. Yes, the statement is true but that does not make it a useful answer.